# Ajax call to controller in Joomla?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

Ok, I installed a component for my Joomla but now I'm working for add a custom counter views.

In controller.php of the component I added the following functions:

```
    function updateView() {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $videoid = JRequest::getVar('videoid');
    if ($videoid) {
        $query = "update #__hdflv_upload SET times_viewed=1+times_viewed where id=$videoid";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->query();
    }
    $query = "select times_viewed from #__hdflv_upload where id=$videoid";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $timeView = $db->loadResult();
    echo $timeView;
    jexit();
}
```

Anyway, in the page I tried to call this function with php and works fine, but with cache enabled the script stop working. They said to me that in Joomla the counter views should always be in Ajax. But I'm that expert on Ajax, I tried with this but with no result:

```
    <script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?option=com_contushdvideoshare&task=updateView&format=raw',
    success: function(data){
                if(!data.length){
            // Throw an error
            return;
        }

       $('.container').html(data);

    }
});
</script>
```

Can somebody help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a sql injection vulnerability in your first code it should be:

```
function updateView() {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $videoid = JRequest::getInt('videoid');
    if ($videoid) {
        echo '0';
        jexit();
    }
    $query = "update #__hdflv_upload SET times_viewed=1+times_viewed where id=".(int)$videoid;
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();

    $query = "select times_viewed from #__hdflv_upload where id=".(int)$videoid;
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $timeView = $db->loadResult();
    echo $timeView;
    jexit();
}
```

Use JRequest::getInt('videoid') if you want to retreive an integer, Joomla will check and validate the input for you.

You can also cast to int directly in your sql query which is a good habit.

Then, get queries are cached. You have two solutions to change this behaviour :

- Post requests are never cached so use an ajax post request
- Specify in the ajax function that this request should not be cached

Here is the js code modified

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?option=com_contushdvideoshare&task=updateView&format=raw',
    method: "POST", //Use post method
    cache: false, //Specify no cache
    success: function(data){
        if(!data.length){
            // Throw an error
           return;
        }
       $('.container').html(data);
    }
```